# Drools on Wildfly LDAP authentication, properties authorisation

Tags: xml, ldap, wildfly, drools

After authentication to business-central (drools-workbench), the user has no authorization. I have the LDAP search config confirmed in the  block and using the `properties` files in the authorization block.

The "properties" config works fine when LDAP is off for auth and using local property files for authentication also but when LDAP is on for authentication, authorization breaks. The files are in the correct location with correct permissions. This is in the docker container built from here: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/drools

XML looks like this:

```
 <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="false"/>
                <ldap connection="ldap" base-dn="ou=Users,ou=XXXXXXX,dc=XX,dc=XXXXX">
                    <username-filter attribute="sAMAccountName"/>
                </ldap>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
```

I expected the user to have admin access as it works when I use `properties` files for authentication as well as authorisation. I do get an odd error when ldap is on for authentication:

> 09:06:27,486 ERROR
>   [org.uberfire.ext.security.management.BackendUserSystemManager]
>   (default task-1) UsersManagementService initialization failure:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Properties file for users not found at
>   './standalone/configuration/application-users.properties'.

Which seems obvious but not as the file exists and has the users etc in it, correct permissions.

Comment: I think you need to change authorization settings to ldap as well to fix this issue

Comment: Yes you are probably right, from the docs I thought I could mix them. I've tried a few different permutations of the group search from ldap but it doesn't log me in at all then, I will continue with trying to get that working. Thanks a lot for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have confirmed the group search config so this is no longer relevant.